# Windows Server 2008 automatically restarts at a particular time

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a problem with a Window Server 2008 (SP2). The last three days my server has been restarting automatically at 10.30 am - after not booting proper blue screen show than I am soft mode boot here shutdown the server after normal boot after working

Comment: Have you checked your Windows Task Scheduler for any shutdown instructions?

Comment: What error is shown on the blue screen?

Answer (score 2):

Check the System event log for a reboot reason.

Look for source (aka Provider) EventLog, id 6009 to identify reboot times (this logs the OS version early in the startup process).

Then check:

- Source  "USER32" event id 1074 for shutdowns initiated normally by a process (and if you have the process tracker running, the reason entered)
- Source "WER-SystemErrorReporting", id 1001 for BSOD details

Answer (score 0):

Blue screen error means you have some fault in your hardware, try to replace RAMS also if you have any newly installed hardware like Sound Card or LAN Card try to remove it and check again if it works. Also what is the Blue Screen Error Code, like PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA ? OR similar you will get on top , so we can better explain you.

Comment: also if you have it the error number e.g. 0x0000008A